# Return the ISO code from a currency formatted cell

Tags: vba, excel

The user, through a userform, can insert a numeric value (say `1,000,000`) and an ISO code (say `USD`). When he will validate, the value will be printed in range A1 and will be formatted as currency through the use of the following macro-recorded line of code:

```
.Range("A1").NumberFormat = _
            "_-[$" & Me.ISOTextBox.Value & "] * #,##0.00_-;-[$" & Me.ISOTextBox.Value & "] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$" & Me.ISOTextBox & "] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
```

Basically, the above is the string to assign the `.NumberFormat` property; in the case of "USD", for example, the string will look like:

```
"_-[$USD] * #,##0.00_-;-[$USD] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$USD] * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
```

My question is: if with the above string I **set** the number format, how could I **get** it?
I could clearly make string parsing, and this is the currently "horrible" solution I'm adopting for extracting the 3-letters ISO code:

```
ISOcode = Left(Replace(Split(Range("A1").NumberFormat, "[")(1), "$", ""), 3)
```

**Note:** the above code is splitting the all `NumberFormat` by `[`, hence taking the second element (starting with `$USD`), replacing the `$` with `""` and taking the first three letters, standing to the standard of ISO codes that are always 3-letters long).

Documentations are very poor on this: does anyone know if there's a way of properly get the *ISO code* from the currency format (without turning into an unelegant string parsing)?

Comment: Maybe there's as well a more elegant way to set the currency code into the NumberFormat?

Comment: Since the format is just a string, it seems like you can't escape parsing that string, unless you also store that ISO code somewhere else (eg in a comment on the cell)

Comment: @TimWilliams unfortunately no, the ISO code is input through the form and stored into the cell _as number format_ and not as string into a separate cell. I hope the code will be stable then, I don't like trusting too much string parsing in this case.

Comment: In that case, the best you could do would maybe be to implement a regexp-based parser to extract the ISO code (though that would limit you to Windows...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you will need to parse the string, but the ISO code can be extracted slightly more cleanly using:

```
If InStr(Range("A1").NumberFormat, "[$") <> 0 Then _
ISOcode = Mid(Range("A1").NumberFormat, InStr(Range("A1").NumberFormat, "[$") + 2, 3)
```